# Conjugates of an $r$-cycle in $S_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> How many conjugates does a cycle of length $r$ have in the permutation group $S_n$?

I tried to find them but failed.

Answer (score 2):

It can be shown that $a$ and $b$ are conjugate in $S_n$ iff they admit cycle decompositions with the same cycle lengths (the proof can be easily found, for example, look [here](http://www.math.wm.edu/~vinroot/415conj.pdf)). So, two cycles are conjugate iff they have the same length.

To count all cycles of length $r$ in $S_n$, you can proceed as follows. Let $S_n$ act on $\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}$. First, choose any subset of size $r$ - there are $\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$ of them. Then, choose a cyclic permutation of the latter - there are $(r-1)!$ of them. Combining, we get $\frac{n! (r-1)!}{r! (n-r)!} = \frac{n!}{r (n-r)!}$.

Comment: Yes I understand.

Comment: The ans is: nPr/r

Comment: @avijitkundu I don't understand you. What is P in nPr/r ?

Comment: Its meaning is : n!/(n-r)!

Comment: @avijitkundu no, that's wrong. Updated the answer.

Comment: You want to know what is P , so P= n!(n-r)!.

Comment: @  lisyarus): P represents permutation

Comment: But the main ans is n!/{r×(n-r)!}

Comment: @avijitkundu ah, got it, sorry :)